# Проблема в сериализации

Tags: java

При сериализации вылетает IOExeption "Problem with I/O" не могу понять что сделал не так

Main.class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

static Employer[] employers = new Employer[2];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    write(employers);

    show(employers);

    serealization(employers);

    deserealization(employers);

}


public static void write(Employer[] employers) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++){

            System.out.println("Enter surname: ");
            String surname = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter ID number: ");
            long idnum = scan.nextLong();
            System.out.println("Enter year: ");
            int year = scan.nextByte();
            System.out.println("Enter payment: ");
            double payment = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\n");

            employers[i] = new Employer(surname , name, idnum, year, payment);
        }

}

public static void show(Employer[] employers){

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%15s | %10s | %11s | %4s | %7s", "Surname" , "Name", "ID number", "Year", "Payment");
    System.out.println("\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------");

    for(int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
        employers[i].getStatus();

    System.out.println("\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------------");
}

private static void deserealization(Employer[] employers) {

    try{
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("People.bin");
        ObjectInputStream inp = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        int employersCount = inp.readInt();
        String[] m = new String[employersCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
            m[i] = (String) inp.readObject();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employers));

        inp.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0x077);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void serealization(Employer[] employers){

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("People.bin");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        out.writeInt(employers.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
            out.writeObject(employers[i]);

        fileOut.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0x02);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Problem with I/O");
        System.exit(0x03);
    }
}

}
```

Employer.class

```
public class Employer {

String surname;
String name;
long idnum;
int year;
double payment;

public Employer(String surname, String name, long idnum, int year, double payment){

    this.surname = surname;
    this.name = name;
    this.idnum = idnum;
    this.year = year;
    this.payment = payment;

}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getIdnum() {
    return idnum;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public double getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

public void getStatus() {

    System.out.printf("%15s | %10s | %11d | %4d | %.1f" , getSurname(), getName(), getIdnum(), getYear(), getPayment());
    System.out.print("\n");

}
}
```

Comment: Покажите стектрейс.

Comment: У вас выбрасывается `IOException`, который вы глушите, записывая в консоль "Problem with I/O", в то время как вся информации - в исключении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо создать массив эмплоеров, а не стрингов и переопределить toString в эмплоере для адекватного вывода в консоль. Как-то так:

```
Employer[] m = new Employer[employersCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
                m[i] = (Employer) inp.readObject();
```

а в классе эмплоер:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employer{" +
                "surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", idnum=" + idnum +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", payment=" + payment +
                '}';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Employer implements Serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

как вам уже ответили. вы должны добавить 
`public class Employer implements Serializable`

Кроме этого, рекомендую использовать String.valueOf() вместо каста.

```
for (int i = 0; i < employers.length; i++)
     m[i] = String.valueOf(inp.readObject());
```